# Local Wordpress Install - wp-admin error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

I have recently installed a local version of my remote wordpress website through MAMP. I can access the front-end but not the back-end (wp-admin)

I installed wordpress locally and uploaded my database files through phpmyadmin.

I then used sql to update the site URLs

I can view the website locally, and I know that wordpress / my database upload is working because I can see some forms I have installed.

But I just get a blank white screen if I try and reach /wp-admin.

I have enabled debugger mode and all I get is

```
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use __construct()
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of wordpress?

Comment: No, I'm on Wordpress 4.4.5 - should that make a difference?

Comment: Empty your plugins folder and try again - see if that works - that error suggests a plugin is throwing an error and causing the admin not to load.

Comment: Thanks, gave that a go but to no avail.

Comment: I do have the error come up on the debugger 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...'

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/.../wp-content/themes/bootstrap-basic-child/functions.php:22) in /Users/...l/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorted! I had some trailing white space in theme functions!

Answer (score 0):

**Download latest version of wordpress from https://wordpress.org**